# Appending to an appendTo

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am receiving a JSON object, inserting this info into a template and then appending this to a DIV. One of the elements that I'm inserting has the id set to device_id.

Once my template html has been inserted I want to select the DIV which has the ID=device_id and insert some further information into it.

I'm assuming the reason why this doesn't currently work is because the DOM hasn't yet updated by the time i'm attempting to select the div with the device_id, but I don't know how to deal with this.

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(msg);
$("#myTemplate").tmpl(obj).appendTo("#message");

jQuery.each(obj, function () {
    $('#' + this.device_id).append('<p>Hello</p>');
});
```

The above code is inside a click event. And the DOM will look like this:

```
<div id="message">
   <div class="item">
     <div id="#156846"></div>
     <div id="name"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The JSON being received (msg) looks like this:

```
[{"name":"Person A","device_type":"one", "device_id":"156846"}]
```

How do I insert the 'Hello' into the div where id=this.device_id?

Comment: can you edit you're question and show us what `obj` or `msg` look like ? i asume you're problem is with the `.each` loop

Comment: I've added it in but the this.device_id shows up correctly in an alert so it seems to be iterating through it fine and I can see that the device_id enters the id="" properly (and the this.device_id in the loop matches this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that appendTo() was not the problem. If you can see above,  has a typo. There should be no # as part of the id.

Also, I needed to use $('#1234').find('#item').appendTo(); in order to get a child element that is further down in the hierarchy.